# module 'torchtext.data' has no attribute 'Field'

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

```
from torchtext import data

TEXT = data.Field(tokenize='spacy', batch_first=True, include_lengths=True)

LABEL = data.LabelField(dtype=torch.float, batch_first=True)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 3
      1 from torchtext import data
----> 3 TEXT = data.Field(tokenize='spacy', batch_first=True, include_lengths=True)
      4 LABEL = data.LabelField(dtype=torch.float, batch_first=True)

AttributeError: module 'torchtext.data' has no attribute 'Field'
```

i want to do text classification and this happen.how to solve this problem?

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-932f701c711a> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 from torchtext.data.utils import get_tokenizer
----> 2 from torchtext.legacy import data
      3 
      4 TEXT =get_tokenizer("spacy",language="en_core_web_sm")

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchtext.legacy'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
from torchtext.legacy import data
```

`torchtext.data.Field` is now `torchtext.legacy.data.Field`

everything remains same.

```
torchtext.data.Field -> torchtext.legacy.data.Field
```

Here is the full list of changes in `Torchtext 0.9.0 release`

```
torchtext.data.Pipeline -> torchtext.legacy.data.Pipeline
torchtext.data.Batch -> torchtext.legacy.data.Batch
torchtext.data.Example -> torchtext.legacy.data.Example
torchtext.data.Field -> torchtext.legacy.data.Field
torchtext.data.Iterator -> torchtext.legacy.data.Iterator
torchtext.data.Dataset -> torchtext.legacy.data.Dataset
```

git link : https://github.com/pytorch/text/releases/tag/v0.9.0-rc5